# Z Buffer Reordering error when trying to create a surface plot from .csv-file

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I am having trouble creating a surface plot from this .csv file. I receive the following error message:

```
Package pgfplots Error: An internal error occured during z buffer reorderingsto be wrong, you might want to provide rows and cols manually.. \end{tikzpicture}
```

An okay plot is being put out... But I am honestly lost at the error message. Is there any way to create a surface plot without having to provide the mesh/rows=26 info? I have the feeling this is what is causing the problem, although I am not sure why... It might also be my csv-file. Does anyone have an idea what might be wrong? Below a MWE and the csv file.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[colormap/viridis]
    \addplot3 [surf, shader=interp,mesh/rows=26, mesh/check=false] table[col sep=comma] {Figures/Data/Qualitative/testinho5.csv};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1W7sd3pwMYfhJtB24MibmKEIEiQxk7XbD/view?usp=sharing) is the .csv file.

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/134805), instead of a code snippet.

Comment: Also, please do not link to external files. It may be sufficient to post a small part of our CSV file.